# How to make inverted shadow on UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, uilabel

I'm trying to get an "embed" effect on my UILabel in my app.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

I want it to look like the font is "embedded" or pressed into the background.  Please note this font is dynamic, the UILabel will be changed programmatically.

Any ideas as to how this can be done, or as to what font looks like this?

Thanks in advance!

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Edit:** Thanks to *fbrunel*, I figured out how to do it.  Check out the result, though.

[image]

It really doesn't look very nice, any ideas why?

Comment: Try using `[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5]` instead of pure white. You can also experiment with different shades of grey (and different alpha values). For a slightly different effect, you can try making the .shadowOffset `(0, -1)`. You'll need to tweak the shadow colour until it looks good with the text and background colour that you're working with.

Comment: That does look much better, thank you Nick!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's done using an "inverted" shadow on the text. On UILabel you have two properties to do this: shadowColor and shadowOffset (the direction of the shadow).

```
label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: If you add four spaces before any lines of code, they'll appear in a nice block with a monospace font, just for readability's sake.

Comment: How can I make the shadow more visible?  I tried your code and I can't really tell if it works or not because I just can't see it.

Comment: You can't control with width of the shadow with this method, it's a matter is choosing the right colors to have a proper contrast -- to make sure the code works, try a funny color (like red) and play with the direction.

Comment: Okay, I found what I was doing wrong.  I hadn't linked my label with IB's label, thus the "no change" issue. :)  Once I got it fixed, though, I noticed that it looks pretty ugly.  I put a picture in my post above.

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what kind of effect you want to achieve, but using regular fonts (vs. italic) on a light gray background (instead of green) would definitely help -- it's really a question of contrasts.